# CSS - Media query responsive design - same height but width increases

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on responsive design. My goal is to make my website responsive for all sizes.

Generally, I increase the **font-size** of my elements as the width of the device increases.

But what if the width increases and the height remains the same? I was thinking about this scenario while creating a responsive design.

ex: **400x300 500x300 600x300**

In this scenario, as width increases I increase the font-size. But the height stays the same leading to oversized elements because the height stays the same, when the font-sizes are increased.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right but the height will change accordingly to the font size if you didn't set a fix height to the element. see here: https://jsfiddle.net/9L4kaq1p/

Comment: use AND in media query to target specific width and height eg.@media (min-height: 500px) and (min-width: 580px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}

Comment: The height of what? Device? There are already all sorts of device widths, heights and ratios and your current way of doing things was OK, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

So as other users have said before what you want to do first is include this meta tag in your html header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

then you would go to your CSS file and select a certain veiw size.

```
@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width:400px){
     .myClass{
       height: 18em;
       font-size: 1em;
     }
    }
```

This @media allows the CSS to run ONLY when the viewport is within the specified range, in this case between 300px and 400px. You can treat it just as any normal CSS modification, change height, font size, color, background etc. Just remember to open and close your @media with curly brackets{} just like you would when you select an element in CSS.

Answer (score -2):

I use this:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: An explanation as to why this helps would be appreciated

Comment: the content adjusts to the width of the device

Comment: @JonA — That isn't what that means … nor do I see the relevance of this to the question.

Comment: This is what I use on a asp.net and it does the job right.

Comment: @JonA — Your choice of server side technology is irrelevant and, while that `<meta>` element does the job it is designed to do, that isn't the job the question is asking about.

Comment: Sorry about that.